# Как сделать чтобы PHP обрабатывал файл без расширения?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Надо чтобы, например, файл `list` обрабатывался при загрузке как PHP. Что написать в `.htaccess`?
Спасибо!

Может быть так работать должно?

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.()$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php]`

Или

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.()$ - [T=application/x-httpd-php]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью директивы RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^list$ list.php [L]
```

Comment: А чтобы все файлы на сервере, которые без расширения, так обрабатывались?

Comment: У меня это не работает... RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^list$ /list.php [L]

Comment: @MaxNest Ошибся, / лишнюю поставил. У меня так работает, все ок.

Comment: Всё равно не работает((

Comment: @MaxNest у меня - работает. Может, я не так понял? у меня вот в корне сайта лежит файл `list.php`. С этими правилами, если набрать `ваш_сайт/list` - загружается файл `list.php` и правильно работает. Я проверил у себя - все ок. Или у вас именно файл `list`  без расширения `.php`?

Comment: Да. У меня файл без расширения. Мне нужно, чтобы он обрабатывался как PHP

Comment: А впрочем, это получается то же самое. Просто имя файла поменять

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего Вам поможет функция автоматического задания MIME-типа, для тех файлов, у которых он не задан:

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

Comment: Это тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

[Попробуйте так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4687208/5752652):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .
```

Гарантий, что `.` будет воспринята как пустое расширение не дам.  Вы ходите нестандартными решениями, обычно такое делают следующим образом: создают директорию list, в которую кладут один файл - index.php и вызов страницы list приводит к показу дефолтного файла в каталоге.

Comment: Не работает тоже